# how to get to know when the status_code will be 200?

Tags: python, api, http

I request data from API with python.
2 steps:

- I need to request for the url for the data.
  They are obtained by requests.POST method
- with the urls, I can finally request for the data I need.

but the problem is:
the url's resources are not well prepared instantly the urls are obtained. If you want to pull a request for data at once, the outcome is usually failure with status_code != 200 and prompting data not ready.

so, I set a sleep time for random seconds. After some time, I will request the data again until I get it. Although, the code will collapse due to 'Max retries exceeded with url' Error.

How could I get to know the exact time when the url's resources are ready so that I don't need to try again and again?

Comment: Loop -> while ( http.get("website").response != 200 ) sleep 10

Comment: I said, constantly raising a request will cause Http error.

Comment: try catch the error and if it fails there you go, or use ping